# Strange cursor location after using begin{}-end{} snippet in Sublime Text

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I write LaTeX in Sublime Text, if the begin{}-end{} snippet is triggered for a list environment (`enumerate`, `itemize`, `list`, and `description`), a `\item` will be added automatically. But when I press the `Tab` key to leave the environment name field, the cursor will jump to the position before `\item` rather than after it. This looks strange because usually it is expected that the cursor should move to the position after the `\item` command so one can continue to type the text of the list item.

[image: Strange cursor location of Sublime Text snippet]
<sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](https://ws2.sinaimg.cn/large/006tKfTcgy1fq0qddvvvmg30eu0ah4qp.gif))</sub>

I've checked the [snippet code](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/LaTeX/Snippets/begin%7B%7D-end%7B%7D.sublime-snippet) provided in the build-in package `LaTeX` of Sublime Text:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[\\begin{${1:env}}
    ${1/(enumerate|itemize|list)|(description)|.*/(?1:\\item )(?2:\\item)/}$0
\\end{${1:env}}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>begin</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
    <description>\begin{}…\end{}</description>
</snippet>
```

The `$0` mark is indeed put **after** the `\item` inserted by the substitution.

I use Sublime Text 3 build 3143. This issue occurs on both macOS High Sierra and Windows 7 (6.1.7601), even when no third-party package is enabled.

If this is not a bug of Sublime Text, what additional configuration am I missing?

Comment: What is your question? Are you just [filing a bug](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core)?

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe Thanks for reminding me the question is missing in my original post. I've already filed a bug at ST's [default package repository](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/1388) instead of ST's core issue repository. I couldn't confirm it is a bug or just because I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What happens when you press Tab a second time?

Comment: @idleberg Pressing Tab again will insert a tab character just on the left of `\item`.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of ST's snippet function, not just related to the LaTeX package. I write an identical snippet except restricting the scope to only the TeX file. The same problem still exists.